# Can I use foreach for different member types in C#?

Tags: c#, foreach

I need something like this:

```
public class hello
{
   public int age;
   public string name;
}
```

in a method:

```
   var speech = new hello();
   speech.age = 35;
   speech.name = "Robert";
   foreach(var element in speech)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(element);
   }
```

Is this possible?

I doubt whether this code is correct or not.

Comment: It's fairly uncommon to actually need to do this.  Are you sure this is necessary and that the underlying goal (which we don't know) wouldn't be better solved with a different approach entirely?

Comment: For an object as simple as this you can probably get away with a simple override of `.ToString()`. Then you would just need `Console.Writeline(speech);`. You can customize that override to your liking also, `public override string ToString() => $"{name}, aged {age}" ;`

Comment: Use properties for public members, not public fields, ex. `public int Age { get; set; }` & `public string Name { get; set; }`